# Laravel get posts by category

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the posts for a category using Laravel Eloquent 5.3.

I have three tables..

```
**Posts**
id | title | text

**Term_relationships**
term_id | post_id

**Terms**
id | name
```

Eloquent Models

```
class Term extends Model
    {
    public function posts()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'term_relationship');
    }
}


class Post extends Model
{
    public function terms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Term', 'term_relationship');
    }

}

class Term_relationship extends Model
{

}
```

I've tried with for example

```
Term::where('name', $category)->posts->get();
```

Comment: Please provide your Eloquent models. Maybe you have to define the relationships between the models to fetch them properly.

Comment: Okey, I have now updated the post with the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy,

if you want Posts with Terms do this

```
$data = App\Post::with('terms')->get();
```

**in your view :**

```
@foreach($data as $post) // will loop over posts and show title
<div>{{$post->title }} </div>
 @foreach($post->terms as $term)
  <div> {{ $term->title }} </div>  // will loop and echo all terms for current post
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

if you want Terms with posts do this

```
$data = App\Term::with('posts')->where('name', $category)->get();
```

**in your view**

```
@foreach($data as $term) // will loop over terms and show title
<div>{{$term->title }} </div>
 @foreach($term->posts as $post)
  <div> {{ $post->title }} </div>  // will loop and show all posts in each term
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

i think the seconds way suits your needs better since int he first example u will need to use wherehas and a closure

Comment: This only displas the terms title. The $post->title doesnt displays. Are my eloquent models correct?

Comment: every thi.g looks fine! digu in it more! u are closer anyway, try to specify ur foreign keys in model (check docs)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja I know I am a little late, but I found part of this helpful and noticed an error In your 4th block of code where foreach($term->posts as $term) it should be foreach($term->posts as $post). This would be why mattesj was not getting $post->title to display.

Comment: yes, it was a typo! since u know, we write code without testing in here sometime! but thank you! it's fixed now ! i  hope it helped :D